# Add constraints between two sub views programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have two subviews that I created, one in Storyboard one with code, I want to anchor the second view (created with code) to the first view (in storyboard) with some constraints so that the second view sits below the first view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUp()
    }

    func setUp(){

        var view2 = UIView()
        view2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        view2.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)

        self.view.addSubview(view2)
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
    }
}
```

The problem is that I got an error saying `When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view`. Is it bad practice to have some views in storyboard and others in code?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems.

First, the error means that `view1` and `view2` are not both part of `self.view`'s view hierarchy. This is probably because `view1` hasn't been decoded from the storyboard yet. Try moving this code from `viewDidLoad()` to `awakeFromNib()`, which is when they're guaranteed to have been loaded.

Second, you're trying to set the view's frame:

```
view2.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,10,10)
```

This frame will get overwritten by the layout engine making it pointless. Delete this line.

If you're going to use auto-layout, you need to unambiguously specify both the size (height & width) and position (x & y) of the view. The constraint you added only specifies the y-origin, so you also need to add more constraints (probably 3 more) to specify the x-origin, the width, and the height, which are currently undefined.

---

> Is it bad practice to have some views in storyboard and others in code?

No, it's common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one more question: Originally I had `view2.frame = CGRectMake(self.view1.frame.origin.x, self.view1.frame.origin.y + self.view1.frame.height + 10, self.view1.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.3)`, however, this doesn't put `view2` where I wanted without constraints and my question is why doesn't it put it at the location I specified with `(x,y,width, height)` -- if I have to use constraints to specify the location then `(x,y)` in `CGRectMake` seems a little redundant to me.

Comment: @user245954 You should delete that entire line. The entire point of auto layout is that you don't set frames.